# moving files in s3 within the same bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 2 folder inside A bucket `images` & `images_temp`.
I tried it using the website but it is only moving the files from the first page considering that I have 500k files that I want to move, is there a way using the `GUI` to move all the files from `images_temp` to images?

Answer (score 0):

First, please note that there is no 'move' command in Amazon S3. Objects are immutable, so it actually requires the objects to be **copied** and then the original objects **deleted**.

You could write a script to do this, but but with so many objects the easiest method would be to use [Amazon S3 Batch Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/batch-ops.html).

This provides a **copy operation**, but not a Delete operation -- for deletion, you could use [Amazon S3 Object lifecycle management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) to delete all source files after they have been copied.